# Sending POST XML to URL in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an `XML` file i want to send via POST to an URL.

This is my code for it:

```
$url = "http://someurl.com";
$xml = file_get_contents('xml_api_actionsInsert_sample.xml');

$post_data = array('xml' => $xml);
$stream_options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content­Type: text/xml; charset=UTF­8',
        'content' =>  http_build_query($post_data)));

$context  = stream_context_create($stream_options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, null, $context);
```

The requirement is that the header `Content-Type` must be

```
Content­Type: text/xml; charset=UTF­8
```

and that the Request only contains valid XML. The xml file is valid but i'm getting an error from the API

```
error: Request contains no XML
```

Is there a mistake how i send/load the XML? Or should i try another way of sending the Request like `cURL`?

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to send a key-value pair (`xml => '<aaa/>'`)? Maybe it expects you to send just the XML string as `content`.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv, man, i'm blind, thank you, could you please add this as answer so i can accept it?